# Problem with predicate in Alloy

Tags: formal-methods, model-driven-development, alloy

So I have the following bit of code in Alloy:

```
sig Node { }
sig Queue { root : Node }

pred SomePred {
    no q, q' : Queue | q.root = q'.root
}

run SomePred for 3
```

but this won't yield any instance containing a Queue, I wonder why. It only shows up instances with Nodes. I've tried the equivalent predicate

```
pred SomePred' {
    all q, q' : Queue | q.root != q'.root
}
```

but the output is the same.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logic flaw in there:

```
fact SomeFact {
    no q, q' : Queue | q.root = q'.root
}
```

Assume there is an instance with a single queue `Q` that has a given root `R`. When running `SomeFact`, it'd test the only queue available, `Q`, and it'd find it that `Q.root = Q.root`, thus, excluding the given instance from coming to life.

The same reasoning can be made for instances with an arbitrary number of queues.

Here is a working version:

```
sig Node {
}

sig Queue {
    root : Node
}

fact sss {
    all disj q, q' : Queue | q.root != q'.root
}

pred abc() {
}

run abc for 3
```